# Memory heap growth with bitmap

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap

I am selecting a picture from gallery and I display it in an ImageView. However when I run it, I can see HUGE (up to 60MB) of Heap growth.

Here is the code:

```
    else if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){             

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            img = (Bitmap)MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    this.getContentResolver(), 
                    selectedImage);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImgContainer.setImageBitmap(img);       
        img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, boas);
        byteArray = boas.toByteArray();     
        try {
            boas.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**ALL variables have been initialized properly in the beginning of the class, so this is NOT the issue**.

I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: How big is the image, and is this in some kind of loop?

Comment: It is not in a loop. I don't know how big is the image but it's doing it for some images from the gallery. Some images load quick, some make my UI freeze and consume lots of memory. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

```
img = (Bitmap)MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    this.getContentResolver(), 
                    selectedImage);
```

everytime u r creating new object and assgning it to img.
changing it may work.

Edit :

// this can be ur singleton class

```
public class ImageHelper {

    private static ImageHelper imageHelper;

        private Bitmap imageBitmap;

        private ImageHelper() {


          imageBitmap = //source of ur image

        }

        public static ImageHelper getInstance() {
        if(imageHelper==null) {
            imageHelper = new ImageHelper();
        }
        return imageHelper;
        }

        public Bitmap getImage() {

            return this.imageBitmap;
        }

}
```

By doing this , u will have only 1 object of ImageHelper which will hold only 1 copy of the image.

In case u have a diferent point to set the image, like after u pick from the gallery,

u can have a setter method or this,

```
public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.imageBitmap = image;
}
```

Which u can call as

```
ImageHelper.getInstance().setImage(image);
```

From wherever u want to use it, u can do it by

```
ImageHelper.getInstance().getImage();
```

Comment: By changing it means u can have a static object of a singleton class holding that image bitmap, and u can use just that bitmap wherever u need instead of creating new bitmap again and again.

Comment: Logcat gives an out of memory exception. The heap grows up to 60MB sometimes.
Sorry, I am new to programming and Android, I don't understand your answer. What is a singleton? I mean, I dont understand your suggestion. Thanks a lot